# Reading one video frame and its corresponding audio frame in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm fairly new to Matlab and I'm trying to process a video and audio stream. for that i came up with the following code snippet:

```
file = 'someMovie.avi';

video = VideoReader(file);
[y,Fs] = audioread(file);
audioInfo = audioinfo(file);

while video.hasFrame()
    videoFrame = video.readFrame();
    audioFrame = 
end
```

My problem is that for every video frame i read, i need to "load" its corresponding audio sample/block, what's exactly i need write in order to fill **audioFrame** correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as an "audio frame." It's very likely that the audio samples in your movie aren't even specifically aligned to the frames. If you just want the approximate audio data during the nominal 1/framerate period that each video frame is displayed, you'll need to build that from the output of `audioread` (just basic math).

Comment: The video has a framerate `fr`, and the audio has a sampling rate `Fs`. The ratio between the two, `fs / Fs`, tells you how many audio samples `n` are there per video frame. In your loop, just process each time the next ´n` audio samples.